# Lotus Notes Embedded view

Tags: view, lotus-notes, document

I have a strange problem in Lotus Notes. In the bottom of a Notes document (main) an embedded view is placed.

When I open the main document and scroll down an click on the embedded  view; then focus i shifted to the top of the main document.

If anyone of you clever guys knows the reason, then I would like to know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do NOT post code that doesn't have anything to do with your problem. The reason is probably a post back, so start by googling that.

Comment: @SubliemeSiem: Unfortunately it didn't do the trick.

Comment: As far as I know, the reason is not related to a programming issue or an issue which can be solved by coding. It is one of many strange Lotus Notes tricks it does sometimes. Try the following steps to overcome this behaviour: 1. Change the width of the embedded view. Make it smaller. 2. Add more focusable elements after the embedded view element, such as fields, hotspots, buttons, etc.

Comment: @Rafael Osipov Your answer did the trick. If you want the credit, then please make a solution

Comment: @LarsHansen Not for credit purposes, but to let others who face the same issue find this answer easily, I copied my comment as an answer. I am glad it helped you to solve your task :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the reason is not related to a programming issue or an issue which can be solved by coding. It is one of many strange Lotus Notes tricks it does sometimes.

Try the following steps to overcome this behavior:

1. Change the width of the embedded view. Make it smaller.
2. Add more focusable elements after the embedded view element, such as fields, hot-spots, buttons, etc.